# wpf create style for named element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to add style to xaml element **without editing the element**?

for example:

xaml element:

```
<Grid>
     <Grid x:Name="A">content A</Grid>
     <Grid x:Name="B">content B</Grid>
</Grid>
```

and style:

```
<Style x:Key="StyleForA" TargetName="A" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}" >
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="StyleForB" TargetName="B" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}" >
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
</Style>
```

UPD:
I have a project with a lot of styles (aero, black, etc ).

And if I edit the element `Style="{StaticResources StyleForA}"` I must edit all styles. 
So I need to create local style that affected to named element.

Comment: You can utilize style inheritance (see [`BasedOn`](http://www.wpftutorial.net/StyleInheritance.html)) or default style *"propagation"* (`TargetType` without `x:Key` will apply style to all children elements of that type).

Comment: Use BasedOn as I write on the first answer.

Answer (score 2):

Natively you can't.

But without touching your XAML, you can do it very easily using code :

```
    Grd1.Style = (Style) this.Resources["GridKey"];
```

Pure XAML approach using `Blend behaviors`,

```
<Grid x:Name="Grd1">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <ic:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Style" Value="{DynamicResource GridKey}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I use this style on my App.xaml to add a teplate around all aplication controls with error:

```
<Style x:Key="BordaTemplate" TargetType="Control">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">                           
                        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">                           
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="myControl"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                    Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>


 <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource BordaTemplate}" />        
        <Style TargetType="PasswordBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource BordaTemplate}" />
        <Style TargetType="DataGrid" BasedOn="{StaticResource BordaTemplate}" />
        <Style TargetType="ListBox"  BasedOn="{StaticResource BordaTemplate}" />
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource BordaTemplate}" />
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource BordaTemplate}" />
    <Style TargetType="DatePicker"  BasedOn="{StaticResource BordaTemplate}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Not like as you have defined using `target` but if you want to apply a `style` to a specific `control`. then use below:

```
 <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="A">
            <Button.Resources>
                <Style  TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Style>
            </Button.Resources>
            content A</Button>
        <Button x:Name="B">
            <Button.Resources>
                <Style  TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </Style>
            </Button.Resources>
            content B</Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

Or probably create a base style and then create a `BasedOn` style for your controls.

**Update:** If you only want to be concerned about the style at a time and be sure of impacted elements:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style  TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="First" >
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
    <Style  TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="Second" >
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="A">
        <Button.Resources>
            <Style  TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource First}" />                  
        </Button.Resources>
        content A</Button>
    <Button x:Name="B">
        <Button.Resources>
            <Style  TargetType="{x:Type Button}"  BasedOn="{StaticResource Second}" />                    
        </Button.Resources>
        content B</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I want to get answer: it is possible without editing element?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by editing element? can you elaborate?

Comment: @Dr_klo for your perspective, adding an update in answer.

Comment: As I said on my answer, you can do this adding the style in App.xaml

Comment: @KyloRen I update my question. 
I try to avoid mistakes when in any style is not found the key

Comment: @Dr_klo sorry, there is no such shortcut. Styles are resources and have been designed as reusable components without worrying about the implementation specific type(sub types can use parent styles). It's must be handled at where we are using the style not before then that. It's one way kind of flow AFAIK. Doesn't my update in answer solves the problem?

Comment: They want to target an element based on name.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a default style and you can override the properties you want on your local style.

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="Default">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter> 
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="StyleForA" BasedOn="{StaticResource Default}" TargetType="Button" >
                <Setter   Property="Background"  Value="Red" ></Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="StyleForB" BasedOn="{StaticResource Default}" TargetType="Button" >
                <Setter   Property="Background"  Value="Green" ></Setter>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource StyleForA}" Width="100" x:Name="A" Click="Button_Click" Height="100">Test A</Button>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource StyleForB}" Width="100" x:Name="B" Click="Button_Click" Height="100">Test B</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```